# Retrieve an iTunes Track object from its high/low persistent ID

Tags: com, itunes, autohotkey, itunes-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve a track object from its persistent ID using AutoHotkey (v1.1) and iTunes Windows 11. The script works well until I try to use the `ItemByPersistentID` method.

```
objITunesunesApp := ComObjCreate("iTunes.Application")
objITunesLibrary := objITunesunesApp.Sources.Item(1)
objITunesPlaylist := objITunesLibrary.Playlists.Item(1)
objITunesTrack := objITunesPlaylist.Tracks.Item(1)

; Test if objects are OK
MsgBox, % objITunesTrack.Name ; Display the song name - OK

; Get high and low IDs
intIDHigh := objITunesunesApp.ITObjectPersistentIDHigh(objITunesTrack)
intIDLow := objITunesunesApp.ITObjectPersistentIDLow(objITunesTrack)
MsgBox, %intIDHigh% %intIDLow% ; Display: "-1071797520 -947434212" OK

; Try to get the track again using the persistent IDs
objTrackByID := objITunesLibrary.ItemByPersistentID(intIDHigh, intIDLow)
; Error:  0x80020006 - Name unknown
; Specifically: ItemByPersistentID

MsgBox, % "objTrackByID.Name: " . objTrackByID.Name ; name empty
```

Am I calling `ItemByPersistentID` the right way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the error in the original script:

```
objTrackByID := objITunesPlaylist.Tracks.ItemByPersistentID(intIDHigh, intIDLow)
```

`ItemByPersistentID` is a method of Tracks collections.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone else provide an answer about the `ItemByPersistentID` function, I found this other approach. More tedious because you have to save 4 IDs about a track to be able to retrieve it by ID(s), but it works.

```
objITunesunesApp := ComObjCreate("iTunes.Application") ; will launch iTunes if not running
objITunesLibrary := objITunesunesApp.Sources.Item(1) ; main library
objITunesPlaylist := objITunesLibrary.Playlists.Item(1) ; main playlist
objITunesTrack := objITunesPlaylist.Tracks.Item(1) ; first track

; get IDs for this track
sourceID := objITunesTrack.sourceID
playlistID := objITunesTrack.playlistID
databaseID := objITunesTrack.trackDatabaseID
trackID := objITunesTrack.trackID
; check track name to see if we can retrieve the same track by IDs
name := objITunesTrack.name

MsgBox, % ""
    . "sourceID: " . sourceID . "`n"
    . "playlistID: " . playlistID . "`n"
    . "databaseID: " . databaseID . "`n"
    . "trackID: " . trackID . "`n"
    . "name: " . name . "`n"

; retrieve the same track using IDs
objTrackByID := objITunesunesApp.GetITObjectByID(sourceID, playlistID, trackID, databaseID)

MsgBox, % "objTrackByID.name: " . objTrackByID.name ; same name as previously -> WORKS!
```

`sourceID` and `playlist` won't change for all tracks in the same playlist. So we only need to save 2 IDs per track to be able to retrieve a track. Finally, not much more complex than retrieving by `ItemByPersistentID` if whenever it is feasible.

Comment: Just have to take into account that these IDs are not persistent. As stated in the object model doc: "An IITObject uniquely identifies a source, playlist, or track in iTunes using four separate IDs. These are runtime IDs, they are only valid while the current instance of iTunes is running."